# Issue with raspberry pi and kodi autostart

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, kodi

I installed **kodi** on my **raspberry pi** on raspbian. I read the easiest way to auto start **kodi** when I turn it on it to change the `/etc/default/kodi` file and set `ENABLE = 1`.

Whenever I try this both the app I use as remote (flex remote - ios) and the mouse connected to the raspberry won't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

can't remember exactly, but inside `/etc/default/kodi` you can also specify a user. Default it should be set as `kodi` but if you haven't edited that user this might be a source of problems. Try changing that user to `pi` or give the right permissions to the kodi user